# AFTER INSERT trigger not working in MySQL for modifying data in a different column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am kind of new to databases and I have a table **society** which has this attribute of **Total_Fund** and another table named **expenses** with attribute **Amount** which stores all the expenses that society does.

So what I want to do is, whenever there is insertion in expenses, I want to deduct **Amount** in expenses for new entry from Total_Fund in society table.

So here is a trigger which I wrote,

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER deduction 
AFTER INSERT 
ON expenses FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE society 
    SET Total_Fund = Total_Fund -  NEW.Amount
  END ;
  
DELIMITER ;
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, why?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER deduction 
AFTER INSERT 
ON expenses 
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE society 
    SET Total_Fund = Total_Fund -  NEW.Amount;
```

The trigger contains 1 statement - so BEGIN-END and DELIMITER are excess. But if you want to store them nevertheless, then

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER deduction 
AFTER INSERT 
ON expenses 
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE society 
    SET Total_Fund = Total_Fund -  NEW.Amount;
  END $$
  
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: but after this I m getting Error on Insertion ,
13:02:55 INSERT INTO expenses (Type_OF_Expense, Amount, Payment_Date, Payment_Receipt_Number) VALUES ('Event12', '1000', '2021-3-21', '13') Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.172 sec

Comment: @PATHIKGHUGARE Of course. Your query must contain additional WHERE clause, something like `WHERE society.id = NEW.society_id`, for to update one definite row only. Without it all rows in a table will be updated. But this is out of the subject...